# Docker ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I needed space and executed: `docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`

Since then I can't with docker-compose: `docker-compose build`, I get the error: `ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF`.

I tried to remove all images, reinstall docker, but nothing will do: always the same error, after quite some time.

I built on another system and it worked, which *suggests* that this is a wrong-state issue.

Any idea what I should clean?

Using:

```
▶ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.24 (downgraded from 1.26)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:01:32 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24 (minimum version )
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 31 23:35:14 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

▶ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
docker-py version: 2.1.0
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

Comment: have you tried removing `/var/lib/docker` directory completely before reinstalling? CAUTION: this willl remove all volumes,containers,images... make sure you back it up first.

Comment: I had this issue when my build directory contained several gigabytes core dump file. I've tried removing docker directory with no luck, but then simply removing `core` file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is an built in command to remove unused images (Version 1.13+):

```
docker image prune
```

Now to handle the situation:

- Stop Docker Service

  ```
  systemctl stop docker
  ```
- Backup `/var/lib/docker` then:
- Remove `/var/lib/docker`
  Caution: This will remove images, containers, volumes, ... make sure you back it up first.

  ```
  rm -rf /var/lib/docker
  ```
- Start Docker service

  ```
  systemctl start docker
  ```

**Update:**

As noted in the other answer, In somecases it might be file permissions issue. Please review permissions.

Comment: You're good! :) How does backing it up helps me since I'll have to rebuild anyway, right? It's fine because it is my development machine.

Comment: Usually ppl have lots of images and containers with volumes, and after a couple of days they remember data is missing, so I always encourage for backing up.

Comment: Gotcha. But if I want to restore my images, I simply need to restore `/var/lib/docker/image` and it will work out-of-the-box?

Comment: It should, but i havent tried that myself, another way would be using docker save  and docker load command.

Comment: Did all of this and it didn't help. Problem was permissions as per the other answer.

Comment: My case was file permissions

Comment: My case - not file permissions but I had a few of the files open in Notepad++ which apparently was interfering with things, closed it and everything worked - strange.

Answer (score 71):

I had the same issue and the approved answer didn't work for me.

Turns out I had a file with permissions which didn't allow the user running docker-compose to read it. After removing the file everything was OK

Comment: And what file it was?

Comment: @dondublon doesn't matter. depends on what you have among the files docker is trying to build with. just `chown -R` your project folder to the user it's supposed to have. In my case, one of my containers wrote a file which was root owned and had no read permission for anyone except for owner

Comment: When I was looking for an answer, I ignored yours because thought that there is nothing to do with permissions in my case. I was wrong. In one folder I had a file marked as "crashed data". This file was likely generated by docker container and it didn't have access permissions. So guys don't repeat my mistake, check all your project folders carefully.

Comment: This was the answer for me. A previous docker run had left a bash_history file owned by root in the project folder.

Comment: I also had written a file from within the container into a mounted host volume that happened to be in the same directory as the compose resources. chown -R $USER fixed it.

Comment: I had this issue and was able to resolve it by adding the path to the `.dockerignore` file. Thankfully, I didn't need this file to be part of the build context.

Comment: I accidentally run I OpenVPN with  `sudo openvpn` in the directory of my project and this create a log file `ovpn-status.log`which belongs to `root`, so deleting that log file fix my problem.

Comment: consider `sudo chown :docker -R /var/lib/docker`

Comment: Be like @Desprit - I couldn't find any unusual files, but I felt inclined to just delete everything and re-clone. I committed and pushed all my changes, making sure I recognized all the files in the change set. Then I deleted and re-cloned my repo. Deleting the files required admin permissions - so something was there, probably hidden somewhere. After a fresh clone, I was able to build again.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was a permission error.
I walked against the same exact issue as PR,
`ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF`
My solution is dirty but worked for me

`chown -R 777 /foo/bar/project`

You almost always want to avoid to set permissions on 777, 655 is more reasonable.

```
0 = ---
1 = --x
2 = -w-
3 = -wx
4 = r-
5 = r-x
6 = rw-
7 = rwx
```

A more detailed explanation can be found here:
https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions

Answer (score 6):

#### Solving this error for good

`docker build` needs read access to every file in the context directory tree. To avoid permission issues, add all your mounted directories to [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file except those required for the build. For example, for this `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    myservice:
        build: .
    volumes:
        - './etc:/etc/myservice'
        - './log:/var/log/myservice'
```

Add a `.dockerignore` file with this content:

```
/etc
/log
```

The problem will go away no matter the permissions of the files in your mounted directories.

#### How to get a more informative error

The `docker-compose` error is not very informative so you can try to run `docker` on each build just to get detailed information:

```
$ docker build .
```

You will get an error like this:

```
error checking context: 'no permission to read from '/home/david/docker/myservice/log/2020161.log'.
```

Comment: docker build .  <--- this did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue turned out that a Docker Pull was hung, so I CTRL+C'd out of it and tried again. Same error message.

In the end I found some files owned by root in this directory. Giving the files proper permissions fixed the issue.

`chown -R <username>:<group> /var/lib/docker/tmp`

- MAC Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

Comment: consider `sudo chown :docker -R /var/lib/docker/tmp`

Answer (score 4):

there could be several different problems. You can find out the problem by checking the issue that docker build is throwing.

The problem is that docker-compose build will suppress the information of the issue. To find out what the issue is

do not use:

```
docker-compose build XXX
```

instead, open your docker-compose.yml, find the *build:* tag of the service is giving you an issue, e.g.

```yaml
services:
   yourservice: 
       build: yourservice-directory/
```

and then run:

```
docker build yourservice-directory
```

after this you will see what is the issue.

Comment: I did `docker build --file <dockerfile> .` and got this error: `error checking context: 'no permission to read from '/<my repo>/core.19168''.`. I deleted those files and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Reference:
https://medium.com/the-code-review/clean-out-your-docker-images-containers-and-volumes-with-single-commands-b8e38253c271

1. Clean up containers, images, volumes and networks on your system:
*docker system prune --all --force --volumes*
2. *docker-compose up*

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried looking through permissions, docker reset, docker system prune, deleting all containers, deleting all images (dangling or otherwise), reading about everything that there is surrounding this issue and have had no success. Try uninstalling docker and re-installing the stable version.

Although, the error I was struggling with was : `Error processing tar file(exit status 1): mkdir /some/path/name: no such file or directory`

Comment: I did all the above mentioned solution and nothing worked for me, and lastly I tried upgrading docker packages and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was a .dump file created by one of my project's scripts.

`docker-compose` passes the context to the engine as a tar file, therefore, the `build` command was packing a tar (the .dump file) inside another tar file (the docker context) hence throwing an unexpected EOF on the context.

Since I don't need the .dump file in the container, I added it to my .dockerignore file.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue when i changed the Dockerfile location in a **python project**. I tried the accepted answer and didn't work for me.

I resolved the problem by running :

```
find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs sudo rm -r
```

On the project root.

The problem was that docker-compose build  was trying to read files inside **pycache** folders.

Maybe this also can be fixed with a proper use of .dockerignore but i dind't try it

Hope this helps.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the memory for Docker, it fixed the issue for me.

Docker memory setting in Preferences was set to 2GB, so when pulling the ~3GB image, I was getting exactly this error:

```
$ docker pull skymindops/skil-ce
latest: Pulling from skymindops/skil-ce
118c5f2883d6: Pull complete 
3d199b2e6224: Extracting [==================================================>]  2.902GB/2.902GB
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

Increasing the memory limit fixed it (I also increased the swap, but unsure was it required or not).

Comment: My question is totally irrelevant with the asked question, but how did you specify the memory limit for docker? you mentioned that `Docker memory setting in Preferences was set to 2GB` where did you specify the Preference? I want to set the memory limit to the docker deamon actually.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything from rebooting, reinstalling Docker, and purging `/var/lib/docker`.

**My cause was  something corrupting the build context in my project.** After I ran `git clean` to reset the project directory back to its original state, I was able to `docker-compose`.

Run `git clean -iXd` in your project's root to interactively `git clean`.

Edit: after a while, it happened again. This time, `git clean` didn't fix it. I'm pretty sure it only happens on Ubuntu. My arch coworkers have never encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution:

1. Ensure specify the image name on `docker-compose.yml`
   for example, specify the image name and container_name as django_practice_db/django_practice_web

   ```yaml
   services:
     django_practice_db:
       image: postgres
       container_name: django_practice_db
     django_practice_web:
       container_name: django_practice_web
       build: .
       command: pipenv run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
   ```
2. Copy the project file to another place
3. Go inside the copied project directory
4. Execute `docker-compose build`
5. Go back to the original project directory
6. Execute `docker-compose up`

Not sure why I can build images when I change the folder path.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential cause of this, especially if you're seeing an error like

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /code/node_modules/xxx: no space left on device
```

You might want to check the "disk image size" in the Docker application. You might need to increase the disk size.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in Ubuntu: Ran below command and it worked (just make sure to start again once you are done):

```
/opt/McAfee/ens/tp/init/mfetpd-control.sh stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve for me. You need have your user in docker group (usermod -aG docker $USER):

sudo chmod -R 775 .
sudo chown -R : .

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little bit old now, but I had this problem today and what I figured out was next. When I was exporting my image as a tar file with next command:

```
docker save -o exportedfile.tar myimage/version:latest
```

I exported this in Linux shell instead of CMD. When I do it in CMD everything works fine. I guess there is some difference in -o flag between Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I replaced the .tar file and tried to build again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as OP, but neither the approved answer nor the top voted answer did it for me.

What pointed me in the right direction was a comment under the approved answer by [JGlass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784396/docker-error-error-processing-tar-fileexit-status-1-unexpected-eof#comment99785012_42785775) saying that after closing Notepad++ everything worked properly.

I wasn't using Notepad++, but I did have Visual Studio open. I didn't have any files open either, but I did have the project open in the solution explorer. After closing Visual Studio, the issue was resolved.

In my case it wasn't a permission issue, but Docker was unable to access the file because another application was using it.

Hopes this helps someone.