# docker-compose: "Error processing tar file(exit status 1): permission denied" in CentOS 7

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos7

I just cloned a git project to my CentOS 7 VPS. The project contains `docker-compose.yml` file and I am trying to run `docker-compose up`.

The command is exiting with this single error message

```
ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): permission denied
```

I have run the same project successfully on my local machine. I am using docker-compose version 1.15.0 and Docker version 17.06.0-ce.

Can't figure out why this is happening. Could anybody please help?

Comment: can you try running the command with sudo?

Comment: I'm already the `root` user. Still I tried it and its the same result

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784396/docker-error-error-processing-tar-fileexit-status-1-unexpected-eof