# docker-compose drupal not accepting my database name and throwing error below

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following ***`docker-compose.yml`*** file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  maria_service:
    build: ./db_maria
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mariadb
      MYSQL_USER: joel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql

  drupal_service:
    build: ./website
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/modules
      - /var/www/html/profiles
      - /var/www/html/themes
      # this takes advantage of the feature in Docker that a new anonymous
      # volume (which is what we're creating here) will be initialized with the
      # existing content of the image at the same location
      - /var/www/html/sites
    depends_on:
      - maria_service
```

Here's my working directory:

[image]

Here's the drupal dockerfile where all I'm doing is to pull the drupal image:

1. [image]

Here's the mariadb dockerfile:

[image]

It automatically generate this "db" subfolder seen in the pic below:

[image]

My issue is everytime I enter mariadb on the drupal UI at localhost:8080, it throws this error below: 
[image]

**UPDATES:**

Based on @Tarun Lalwani answer, my issue was that, in the Drupal UI, I would enter my username, password and db name but if you expand that Advanced Options in that Drupal screenshot, you'll see that the HOSTNAME was pointing to "localhost" when it should be pointing to the actual hostname of the mariadb database server which in DOCKER WORLD, the hostname name of a running container is ITS SERVICE NAME i.e "mariadb_service" as seen in the docker-compose.yml file - see screenshot. Hope I wasn't the only newbie that bumped into that and will help others, thanks Tarun Lalwani!!

Comment: In the Advanced options check for host name and if you have that option then set it as `maria_service`

Comment: Thank you that was the issue! I'll update my answer above with a screenshot to help others in the future! BTW I'm new with docker/docker-compose so learning a lot, thank you!

Comment: Would you know why it creates that db folder instead of putting the db stuff into my db_maria directory?

Comment: Thats because you used `- ./db:/var/lib/mysql`. And you should not use `db_maria` as it already has a `Dockerfile`. You should use a empty folder for creating the fresh DB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the Host name also for the DB in Drupal. This db host will be `maria_service` as per the service name from your `docker-compose.yml` file. This needs to be done by expanding the Advanced options

[image: Advanced config]

**Using Environment Variables**

You could also try setting the environment variables for these settings

```
version: '3'

services:
  maria_service:
    build: ./db_maria
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mariadb
      MYSQL_USER: joel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql

  drupal_service:
    build: ./website
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/modules
      - /var/www/html/profiles
      - /var/www/html/themes
      # this takes advantage of the feature in Docker that a new anonymous
      # volume (which is what we're creating here) will be initialized with the
      # existing content of the image at the same location
      - /var/www/html/sites
    depends_on:
      - maria_service
    environment:
      DB_HOST: maria_service
      DB_USER: joel
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_NAME: mariadb
      DB_DRIVER: mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, the reason it kept creating that db folder is because I'm mounting that volume - ./db:/var/lib/mysql instead of - ./db_mariadb:/var/lib/mysql so that resolved that if anyone bumps into that. Lastly though, if I use that environment under the drupal_service, then what do I enter in the drupal UI advanced option, will that just auto populate the hostname on the UI for me and that's the advantage of explicitly setting it up in the environment? Let me try it and let u know!

Comment: That should auto complete the setup and that should be the way to do also. I didn't test this out but picked it from another project on github which used Drupal 7.x, but i guess it should work on Drupal 8.x

Comment: It worked beautifully, it bypassed that screen with the advanced section and automatically started installing Drupal; it's as if it just knew to pick up the environment from there, thank you; just one last question though! Since containers are immutable and won't persist data, I'm mounting my DB folders so they somehow persist no matter where I deploy this docker environment; does that mean that if I kill the container and relaunch a new instance of that image, it'll come up with the old data saved because of the volume mounting or it won't persist the db data?

Comment: Since you have the volume mounted, it will persist, You should not kill the containers but stop them. As killing could risk data loss/db corruption

Comment: To test that, I created two pages on my drupal site, then I just tested stopping the containers and launching them back up with docker-compose up and the drupal content was maintained. I still wanna kill the containers to test the theory that these are just isolated environment that are very easy to bring up and down and pass around through a CI/CD pipeline etc...

Comment: [CONTINUED FROM ABOVE COMMENT] since all the blueprint of the running container is in the image, killing the containers should not affect anything else. I'm going to test killing them and rebuilding the images and confirming whether the two drupal pages are still untouched. Lastly, do u have a Slack or some way to stay in touch? I'm learning a lot of docker stuff and it's nice to have a pal friend to help each other learn and answer questions

Comment: You can join the docker slack community. https://blog.docker.com/2016/11/introducing-docker-community-directory-docker-community-slack/. Lot of people available always

Comment: Thanks, I just deleted all images and my thought was that since the DB is mounted on a volume db_maria on the HOST machine, then when I rebuild a brand new image with docker-compose up, it would just reuse that db_maria data but I'm wrong; I think docker-compose will try to override that db_maria folder everytime I rebuild (not RUN but REBUILD) this image from scratch and thereby causing all of my previous db data to be lost :( It's as if, once you have this drupal site going, you have to backup that db_maria and hope to never have a reason to rebuild the image from scratch or lose all data?

Comment: I get this error when rebuilding from scratch: Error processing tar file (exit status 1): unexpected EOF - this other SO post goes over that(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784396/docker-error-error-processing-tar-fileexit-status-1-unexpected-eof) , seems permissions related but even if I get past that permission issue, I'll still get that db_maria local directory volume to be OVERWRITTEN by the next docker-compose up if I delete all images for whatever reason and wanna rebuild from scratch but still keep my previous db data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161126/discussion-between-pelican-and-tarun-lalwani).