# Error processing tar file (exit status 1): unexpected EOF when building with docker-compose while data directory exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  phab:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PHAB_BASE_URI=https://phab.example.com
        - PHAB_REPO_PATH=/var/repo
        - PHAB_TIMEZONE=Europe/Berlin
        - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=32MB
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8012:80"
    volumes:
      - ./.data/repos:/var/repo
      - ./.data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql/
```

If I try to rebuild after I started the container, I get

```
$ docker-compose build
Building phab
ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

This appears to be due to the `.data` directory. The only "cure" I found was either deleting the directory or moving it *outside* of the project directory. Renaming the directory to eg. `.data1` does **not** fix it.

```
$ sudo mv .data .data1
$ docker-compose build
Building phab
ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
$ sudo mv .data1 ..
$ docker-compose build
Building phab
Step 1/27 : FROM tutum/lamp:latest
---> 3d49e175ec00
Step 2/27 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-curl php5-mysqlnd php5-gd python3-pygments
---> Using cache
[ ... ]
```

I am using docker-compose 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9 abd Docker 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825 on Debian 9.5.

---

I have seen the question [Docker ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784396/docker-error-error-processing-tar-fileexit-status-1-unexpected-eof). However just flushing the `/var/lib/docker` directory does not appear as an option to me. Pruning unused images and even removing the base image before the build does not fix the issue.

Comment: What line of the Dockerfile does your build fail on. Please include the Dockerfile, and also indicate the size of the files being added in the failing build step.

Comment: Maybe add a `.data` line to a `.dockerignore` file? that way it will not be included in the build context sent to the docker daemon

Comment: I had the same issue and tried the answer above but at the end there was a file with wrong permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The following steps solved it:

1.) Stop Docker Service.

```
systemctl stop docker
```

2.) Backup /var/lib/docker.

3.) Remove /var/lib/docker.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

4.) Start Docker Service.

```
systemctl start docker
```

Comment: This also worked for a different "error processing tar" message (not EOF) 
```ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: Error processing tar file(exit status 2): runtime: bad pointer in frame github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/libnetwork/ipamutils.splitNetwork at 0xc00049dd60: 0x8```

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to 18.09 which was just released yesterday. The "unexpected EOF" during a build looks like a known issue with 18.06: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37771

Answer (score 0):

remove files generated by other container, like "db_data", "mysql_data", etc