# Docker CE Install Error - Ubuntu 16.04 ppc64le (IBM Power)

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Following the documentation of how to install docker on the remote server (Ubuntu 16.04 ppc64le (IBM Power)), the first error I run into is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli
```

Then running the hello-world example gives

```
sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
7ed68418e852: Extracting [==================================================>]  1.296kB/1.296kB
docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Anyone experienced something similar?

`$ docker info`

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.06.3-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: overlayfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: nvidia runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: a592beb5bc4c4092b1b1bac971afed27687340c5
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-42-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: ppc64le
CPUs: 64
Total Memory: 256GiB
Name: JARVICENAE-0A0A1883
ID: U7D5:KGDS:HUMN:CCEB:X6JR:5EH7:5XFH:KAFL:6QPA:OXYB:5GAS:EJE5
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784396/docker-error-error-processing-tar-fileexit-status-1-unexpected-eof I think this addresses your “permission denied” error

Comment: @NonCreature0714 Thanks for your answer. That one the issue is `unexpected EOF` which is different. I can not see listed images, the error happens while pulling :(

Comment: I think there are several different issues happening here, starting with not being able to locate docker-ce-cli

Comment: I have tried the official installation script, as well as the answers mentioned here `https://askubuntu.com/a/934417/825546` No `docker-ce-cli` found/installed, permission error persists

Comment: can you please run `docker info` and paste the output?  Are you connected to any NTFS volumes?

Comment: @jcuypers it is added, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Storage driver / backing filesystem doesn't look like its a  supported combination :
[image]

please refer to the full document here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/

Comment: Any way you can make a test with another combination out of the list

Comment: Thanks for the information, I think this could be the reason. Although `aufs` is one of the recommended storage driver, but seems not support to run with `overlayfs` as the backing file systems. However, if that's the case, the error message should be more clear shouldn't it... I see it also mentions need to add the flag or make something trust when starting docker when using `aufs` but the link is broken. I am wondering if that could be the issue.