# figuring out setting 'id_rsa' path in Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, ssh, dockerfile

I am trying to clone github private repo in `dockerFile` to my ubuntu server.
In order to authenticate it, I had to add id_rsa file into root folder.

```
FROM python:3.8.12
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
ADD ./.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
WORKDIR /home/
RUN git clone git@github.com:~~~/~~~.git
```

But when I try to command `sudo docker build image` in `/home/ubuntu`

it returns a message saying `error checking context: 'no permission to read from '/home/ubuntu/.bash_history''.`

So I moved my dockerfile to `/home/ubuntu/abc`
and I changed Dockerfile below

```
FROM python:3.8.12
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
ADD ../.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa <------------------------ HERE
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
WORKDIR /home/
RUN git clone git@github.com:~~~/~~~.git
```

then it returns `ADD failed: forbidden path outside the build context: ../.ssh/id_rsa ()`
Is there any way I can fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: You can only `COPY` files from the `docker build` directory into the image; `COPY ../path` or `COPY `/absolute/host/path` don't work.  But you _really_ don't want to copy your private key into the image, since anyone who gets the image can very easily copy it back out.  I'd recommend running `git clone` outside the Dockerfile instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think (!) that there may be a new recommended mechanism to do this.

My approach has been to create a Personal Access Token (PAD) and then pass it as a build argument when building containers that need to `git clone` repos. This saves `ADD`'ing keys and the credentials are passed in memory only.

```
FROM ...

ARG TOKEN
RUN git config \
    --global url."https://${TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
...
```

And then e.g. `podman build --build-arg=TOKEN=${TOKEN} ...`

Comment: Thank you for a good idea, but it's not the way I want...

Answer (score 0):

If possible, avoid running docker build as `sudo` (by, for instance, [adding your user to the `docker` group](https://askubuntu.com/a/1325376/5470) or, preferably, running a docker daemon in a rootless mode, like [`podman`](https://podman.io/))

You can see a similar [error here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45038500/6309), where a comment adds:

> A previous docker run had left a `bash_history` file owned by root in the project folder.