# How can I access HuggingFace Dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, tar, huggingface-transformers

I want to edit the Dockerfiles that are used to run HuggingFace Spaces. I know how to run them in theory, e.g. for `https://huggingface.co/spaces/suno/bark` it's

```
docker run -it -p 7860:7860 --platform=linux/amd64 registry.hf.space/suno-bark:latest python app.py
```

but I'm getting

```
root@conicserver:/home/conic# docker run -it -p 7860:7860 --platform=linux/amd64 registry.hf.space/suno-bark:latest python app.py
Unable to find image 'registry.hf.space/suno-bark:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from suno-bark
fb668870d8a7: Pull complete 
8a612414e2bc: Pull complete 
2c12f5dee74d: Pull complete 
e8b64516db7f: Pull complete 
5063cc75a5fc: Pull complete 
0b5eea1e39eb: Extracting [======>                                            ]  133.7MB/1.021GB
19026083d6ce: Download complete 
9ec6d9577f70: Download complete 
0b5eea1e39eb: Pull complete 19026083d6ce: Pull complete 
9ec6d9577f70: Pull complete 
4d04e22a64a3: Pull complete c89166c8ea49: Pull complete 
76b0ea444c14: Pull complete bc5a04c3e525: Pull complete c179152e36d5: Extracting  263.4MB/263.4MB771ba14c288e: Download complete 
2899cedea070: Download complete 
2414807518af: Download complete 
25a736419101: Download complete 
67ba7933fa09: Download complete 
46995db4b389: Download complete 
36ad3851a86f: Download complete 
650437900a22: Download complete 
d9d84f975ed8: Download complete 
42ed81d077d9: Download complete 
docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header.
See 'docker run --help'.
root@conicserver:/home/conic#
```

How do I access the Dockerfile to fix this?

Comment: What distro an architecture are you on?

Comment: @RickRackow Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784396/docker-error-error-processing-tar-fileexit-status-1-unexpected-eof)

Answer (score 0):

There are two concerns here:

1. Licences and IP of code
2. Technical logistics

I'll let you deal with the former but you can see what happens inside the prediction app using this:

1. Run `docker run -it <img> /bin/bash` this will start the container with bash
2. Use [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/attach-container) or just regular `cat` and `ls` to view the files and folders.

Typically each `app.py` file will have a gradio app running. You can use the code before launching the gradio interface to inspect the models, etc.